# SharePoint CSOM SendMail From address ignored

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, email

I am sending mail with:

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
{
    var emailp = new EmailProperties();
    emailp.BCC = new List<string>{"a@mail.com"};
    emailp.To = new List<string>{"b@mail.com"};
    emailp.From = "from@mail.com";
    emailp.Body = "<b>html</b>";
    emailp.Subject = "subject";
    Utility.SendEmail(_clientContext, emailp);
    _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The mail is sent but the from address is ignored and my servers from address is used. Can I use a from address with Utility.SendEmail? When I convert my code to use the .NET framework SMTP class the from address is respected.

### Update

When I set my servers from email address in the outgoing email settings in central admin to empty I get the exception: The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: address. This happens even when I set emailp.From = "from@mail.com"

Answer (score 0):

**Try to set** `emailp.From` as below

```
emailp.From = new string[] { "from@mail.com" };
```

---

I think if the email is not correct or not set properly it **by default** use the email that already set at **From Adress** in the `Outgoing Email Settings` in the Central Administration

[image]

Comment: emailp.From is of type string. So this line:
emailp.From = new string[] { "from@mail.com" };
Gives a build error.

Comment: And when I set the outgoing email settings from address to empty I get the exception: The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: address. This happens even when I set emailp.From = "from@mail.com";